# Is there a name for this type of derivation?

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

Given a function $f \colon (x,y,t)\mapsto f(x,y,t)$, suppose I obtain the relation

$$\frac{d f}{d t}= a \frac{dx}{dt} + b \frac{dy}{dt}$$

where $a\colon (x,t)\mapsto a(x,t)$ and $b\colon (y,t)\mapsto b(y,t)$ are functions of $x$ and $y$.

Since $f$'s total derivative is

$$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

I can subtract them

$$\left(a-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\frac{dx}{dt} + \left(b-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$

and deduce that

$$ a = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \quad \text{and}\quad b=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

have to hold for arbitrary $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$. Is there a name for such a formulation, and/or general principles used here? For me, this popped up in thermodynamics.

Comment: What's $a,b$? Constants?

Comment: @YuriyS see the edit.

Comment: I see.By definition from your first equation it follows that: $$a=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$$ $$b=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$$ Despite the fact that $a(x,y)=a(x)$ and $b(x,y)=b(y)$, which is a lucky coincidence, I don't think we can use the total derivative notation here

Comment: What does that mean: $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t},\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$? Shouldn't it be $\frac{d x}{d t},\frac{d y}{d t}$ like it was before?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I think I got it right this time. Speaking of the lucky coincidence, you are also right, this formulation is kind of backwards. This formulation is done to find a definition for $a$ and $b$.